# Scrolling to an element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting a few errors and not sure why.

I just want it to scroll to the parents div ID when it's clicked, it's getting the ID okay as I did a console log, so the issue is the scrolling part.

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: clickedPanel.offset is not a function

JS

```
$('#accordion .panel-heading .panel-title').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next().slideToggle(iconCallback);
    $(".panel-collapse").not($(this).parent().next()).slideUp(iconCallback);
    //scroll to clicked pabel
    var container = $('#accordion'),
        clickedPanel = $(this).parent().attr('id');

    container.animate({
        scrollTop: clickedPanel.offset().top - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop()
    })

    function iconCallback() {
        var iconClass = $(this).is(':visible') ? 'fa-minus' : 'fa-plus';
        $(this).prev().find('i').removeClass('fa-plus fa-minus').addClass(iconClass);
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, did you read the error? Of course the `attribute` `id` does not have a function `offset`.

Comment: In your code example `clickedPanel` is a string, therefore it won't have the `offset()` method

Comment: Oh ok, sorry rather new to jQuery. Any ideas on how to fix it? Guess got most pf the way there haha

Comment: Try to remove `.attr('id')` part.

Comment: Select the object not the attribute. `clickedPanel = $(this).parent();`

Comment: Still getting same error without that.

Answer (score 3):

In your example `clickedPanel` is a string which does not have the `offset()` method. Instead set that variable to be the jQuery object returned from `parent()`:

```
clickedPanel = $(this).parent();
```

Comment: Faster than my shadow! Good!

Comment: Thanks mate, just done that but its still giving me the error.

Comment: Sorry its not giving me an error now but its simply not scrolling though lol

Comment: Could you set up an example of your code in a http://jsfiddle.net. It's hard to diagnose an issue like this without seeing it working (or not working as the case may be)